# send meta box input data without publish button

Tags: php, ajax, metabox

I want to add meta-box in my plugin but i want add two inputs and one button like submit button when i click on submit button then input fields data send to database and received but how this is possible without publish button i never use publish button. please any help with simple code.

code.

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'rt_book_sales' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_rt_book_name_rander', 'rt_book_name_rander' );
add_action( 'save_post', 'rt_book_name_rander', 10, 3 );
function rt_book_sales(){
add_meta_box( 'rt_bk_goal', 'Meta Box Title', 'rt_books_meta_rander', 'post', 'normal', 'high' );  
}
function rt_books_meta_rander(){
?>   
</div class= "wrap">
   <input  type="text" name="book_name" id="book_name" >
   <input  type="submit" class="rt_bk_btn">
</div>  
<?php
}
?>
```

and ajax jquery code.

```
$(document).on('click', '.rt_bk_btn', function(e) {          
e.preventDefault();
var bk_name = $('#book_name').val();

var data = {
'bk_name': bk_name,
'action': 'rt_book_name_rander',
}
$.post(ajaxurl, data, function(resp){   
console.log(resp);
});
```

and save post function.

```
function rt_book_name_rander(){
global $post;

if (isset($_POST['bk_name'])) {
        $bk_name = $_POST['bk_name'];
        update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'rt_book', $bk_name );
    }

    die(0);
}
```

this is my code and no data save in database when i get this data with get_post_meta() function.. where is my problem.

Comment: Where is the problem? Where is the code?

Comment: i add code Max Yadin where is my problem. why data not save.

Comment: Max Yudin where is my problem in my code????

Comment: You probably need to pass the `post_id` in the ajax too.

Comment: how please tell me shibi???

Comment: send me update my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the post id like this

`var post_id = $('input[name="post_ID"]').val();`

See this full working code. BTW its only save the value to the meta in the ajax it won't save it on the publish button you need to add another hook with another function. you can't use the same function that you used in the ajax because the `die()`

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'rt_book_sales' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_rt_book_name_rander', 'rt_book_name_rander' );
function rt_book_sales(){
    add_meta_box( 'rt_bk_goal', 'Meta Box Title', 'rt_books_meta_rander', 'post', 'normal', 'high' );
}

function rt_books_meta_rander($post){
?>
</div class= "wrap">
   <input type="text" name="book_name" id="book_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'rt_book', true )); ?>">
   <input type="submit" class="rt_bk_btn">
</div>
<?php
}

add_action('admin_footer', 'my_admin_add_js');
function my_admin_add_js() {
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $(document).on('click', '.rt_bk_btn', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var bk_name = $('#book_name').val();
                var post_id = $('input[name="post_ID"]').val();
                var data = {
                    'post_id': post_id,
                    'bk_name': bk_name,
                    'action': 'rt_book_name_rander',
                }
                $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(resp){
                    console.log(resp);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}

function rt_book_name_rander(){
    if (isset($_POST['bk_name']) && isset($_POST['post_id'])) {
        $bk_name = $_POST['bk_name'];
        update_post_meta( $_POST['post_id'], 'rt_book', $bk_name );
    }

    die();
}
```